# c# winforms Blocking use of my program when internet is down

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have an MDI application created in Winforms. Initially when it is launched, a login screen will appear where the user enters their account email and password. This is validated online using a web service. Once validated, I hide this login form and launch a parent mdi form. From here the user can launch children form and start using the program. Some simplified code is below.

```
//pass along email and pass to web service
amazonaws.WebService1 MyService = new amazonaws.WebService1();
result = Remote.CheckUser(MyService, email, pass);

//process results

//if ok, launch parent
Main m = new Main();
m.Show();

//start timer which checks for internet every minute
timer1.Start();

//hide this form since closing it will exit altogether
this.Hide();
```

The program is checking every minute in the background whether an internet connection is available, and if there isn't, I pop up the original Login form to allow the user to reconnect once they have internet.

This works fine, however I have an issue in that when the Login form pops up, since I call 'login.Show()', the program in the background is still usable. I want to block usage of the program while the Login form is showing.

I tried launching it as 'form.ShowDialog()', but then after validating their info and hiding it, it shuts down my whole application since hiding a modal window has the same effect as closig it, and since it was originally called in Application.Run(Login()) it will shutdown my application when closed/hidden.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Start your Main form from the Application.Run. Open the Login Window in its constructor or in its Form_Load event.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't an option. My code above is pseudo code, there's a LOT more going on after initially logging in, and the Main form cannot launch without already logging in. At least without making major changes.

Comment: Have you considered disabling all elements on the form behind? The user would be able to see the form still but they'd be unable to edit anything?

Comment: This is essentially what I want. Not sure how to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up simply disabling all controls on all forms when the internet disconnects, apart from the login.

I did this by having this function in my parent form and calling it when the internet disconnects. By having it in the parent form, it also disables all child form controls.

```
public void ToggleControls()
{
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        c.Enabled = !c.Enabled;
    }
}
```

I call it like so

```
var parent = Application.OpenForms.OfType<ParentMain>().FirstOrDefault();
if (parent != null)
{
    parent.ToggleControls();
}
```